# Find SOAP EndPoint for a SharePoint Site

Tags: soap, sharepoint, soapui, talend, soap-client

I have a SharePoint Path where I want to upload a file using Talend. Can anyone please tell me how to get SOAP EndPoint Webservice URL of a SharePoint Site? in tSOAP Component I am providing my SharePoint Path exactly which is giving HTTP 403 Forbidden Error. But Using another valid webservice url inside tSOAP the Job completed Normally.

Comment: This has more to do with Sharepoint than with Talend; I'd say ask it in the sharepoint tag..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Talend ESBConsumer component for calling soap services from your job.

Check more on [here](https://help.talend.com/reader/KxVIhxtXBBFymmkkWJ~O4Q/GFvy7HPw~kxppq8OC24JBg)